# When I want to install TeamViewer 10, why can't I select my system disk as the destination?

Tags: macos, ssd

Seems it happened when I want to install other softwares before (but I can't remember which). I have a 128G SSD as the system disk, but it doesn't even appear as an option in the installer. How can I deal with this?

BTW. My SSD's name is Macintoch SSD, which is not appeared on the following window.

UPDATE: 2014-12-30 I've reinstalled my OS X and now the TeamViewer .pkg can be installed correctly.

[image: GUI to select the distination disk of the installation]

Translation of this window (according to my poor English, messages with en-US locale should be different):

Top: Installing TeamViewer

Left:

- Introduction
- License
- Destination Select
- Installation Type
- Installation
- Summary

Right:

- Select a Destination
- Select the disk where you want to install the TeamViewer software.

  - GlacJAY: ...
  - Macintosh HD: ...
  - TeamViewer: ...
- TeamViewer can't be installed on this disk. You can only install this software on the disk that is running OS X.

Comment: Are you running the installer as Administrator?

Comment: @patrix I'm not very sure. I just run the installer as my main - and only - account, which should has the admin privileges, or does it?

Comment: could you translate the teamviewer message. Also could you check your settings in the the security & privacy for download and install from ?

Comment: @GlacJAY yes, if it's your only account then it will have admin privileges

Comment: @Buscar웃   my security settings are: only from App Store or trusted developers.

Comment: Which version of OS X do you have installed?

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan 10.10.1

Comment: I don't think it's an account permissions thing. If you run the installer using an account that doesn't have the needed permissions it'll prompt you for another account right before it actually starts writing files.

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan yes, it'll show other errors, but not this one.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a silly suggestion but if you select the "GlacJAY" drive and hit the down arrow key on your keyboard does the "Macintosh SSD" drive appear?

Unfortunately the Installer window can't be resized and with the current style of disappearing scrollbars, if there are more than three available disks it might not be obvious.

Comment: I've tried this, but there is only this three options. My SSD is just not there.

Comment: If you eject your removable GlacJAY disk, does it just show two disks then?

Comment: yes, exactly (padding).

Comment: @GlacJAY does "Macintosh SSD" icon appears in sidebar or desktop, when you enable the preference in Finder?

Comment: @nelson I'm not really sure, cause I've reinstalled my system. I think it does appears, according to my memory.